# Replace dynamically custom tags in Woocommerce product short description

Tags: php, wordpress, replace, woocommerce, tags

For a Woocommerce webshop I am using [WooCommerce Brands](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/wc-brands/) plugin and I'm trying to replace dynamically specific custom tags in the product short description by specific product values as:

- The product name
- Product category *(with the term link)*
- Product brand *(with the term link)*

For example, The tags to be replaced could be something like:

- `%product_name%`,
- `%category_name%`
- and `%brand_name%`…

Also, it be great for replaced product category and product brand to have the link to the product category or product brand archive pages.

I'm not sure where to look for. I've searched all over google but I can't find anything related and useful unfortunately.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does mean **"merge tags"** for you? How should be the display? Can you give an example before and after, adding some more details editing your question please?

Comment: Merge tags means the tag gets the data from the product in WooCommerce. For example, if i put the merge tag %product_name% in the description on the backend, the page will display the product name in the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

Here is the way to do it using this custom function hooked in `woocommerce_short_description` filter hook, that will replace specific custom tags by product data values in single product pages short description.

Now as product can have **many product categories** and **many product brands**, I keep only the first one.

The code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'customizing_wc_short_description', 20, 1);
function customizing_wc_short_description($short_description){
    if( is_archive() ) return $short_description;
    global $product, $post;

    // 1. Product categories (a product can have many)
    $catgories = array();
    foreach( wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) as $term ){
        $term_link   = get_term_link( $term, 'product_cat' );
        $catgories[] = '<a class="cat-term" href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term->name.'</a>'; // Formated
    }

    // 2. Product brands (a product can have many)
    $brands = array();
    foreach( wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_brand' ) as $term ){
        $term_link   = get_term_link( $term, 'product_brand' );
        $brands[] = '<a class="brand-term" href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term->name.'</a>'; // Formated
    }

    // 3. The data array of tags to be replaced by product values
    $data = array(
        '%product_name%'  => $product->get_name(),
        '%category_name%' => reset($catgories), // We take the first product category
        '%brand_name%'    => reset($brands),
    );

    $keys   = array_keys($data); // The Tags
    $values = array_values($data); // The replacement values

    // Replacing custom tags and returning "clean" short description
    return str_replace( $keys, $values, $short_description);
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Awesome, it works, except for the %brand_name%. I might be due to the fact the merge tag has to grab it's data from the WooCommerce Brands plugin i'm running. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Hey! Thanks again! Unfortunately the brands code now displays the category. Here is a link to the page :https://power-light.nl/product/artemide-pirce-mini-halo/

As you can see, "Hanglampen" is the category, "Artemide" is the brand.

Comment: @ArjanWassink Sorry I have forget to update some mistake. It's done now and it should work for product brands… Try it again.

Comment: Awesome! It's working perfectly. Thanks a lot LoicTheAztec! One last question tho: Is it possible to style the tags with a little css or a class? I'd like to have an underline on the links.

Again, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ArjanWassink Yes of course, as I have added **classes** for product categories linked tags (`cat-term`) and product brands linked tags (`brand-term`)… So you will use for example something like: `a.cat-term, a.brand-term { color:#96588a; }`